# Is a VM's speed affected by programs running outside of it?

Tags: performance, sorting, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm testing the speed of different sorting methods for a CS class, and although our professor said we didn't need to be *terribly* precise, he still wants us to be careful not to run apps in the background while testing, use a different machine, or do anything to throw the speed of the sorts off.

If I ran the tests in a VM, would the environment outside of the VM affect the speed? Would that help make the tests accurate without having to worry about changes in the apps I have open alongside the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes.

In most scenarios, hosts share their resources with the VM. If you bog down/freeze/crash the host then the VM will be affected.

For those that have more robust servers with better resources, processes running in the host won't affect the VM as much. Because if you have more resources on the host you can assign better RAM and Virtual Processors to the VM so it runs smoothly.

For instance, let's say our host has 64GB of RAM a processor that has 4 cores and 8 threads (such as an Intel® Xeon® E3-1240 Processor).

We can tell VirtualBox, VMware or Hyper-V to assign 32GB of RAM and 4 virtual processors to the VM, essentially cutting the host's power by half.

With this in mind, any processes you run on the host will usually be separate from the VM but if the processes freeze, crash or cause a hard reboot on the host then the VM will be affected regardless of RAM or virtual processors assigned.

In enterprises environments, a hyper-v server should only be used for that purpose and installing/running a lot of processes in the host is usually frowned upon (such as installing/running DHCP, DNS, Web Server (IIS), etc).

So your professor is right to advise against running processes on the host while testing your VM.

Comment: Although. I don't recall seeing this ability in VirtualBox.

Comment: To run a VM with VirtualBox you need to share the hosts' resources with the VM. This applies to any Virtualization software such as Hyper-V or VMWare.

Comment: I was thinking of the CPU resource controls in 2016 Hyper-V. You can limit the root to say, 4 CPUs and give the guest the other 4 CPUs. Then the guest has complete control of its 4 and nothing can disturb it.